# How to instantiate module with variables

Tags: verilog, multiplexer, register, alu, register-file

I declared `alu_result` as a reg because I need it to be a variable data type for my case statement. But when i do this, I cannot pass it my `write_data` in my datapath_tb module. Is there some work around where I can get this to work?

```
module alu(input [31:0] input1, input2, input [2:0] control);
parameter SIZE=32;
reg [31:0] alu_result;
reg overflow;

always @(*)
begin
    case(control)
        0: alu_result = input1 & input2;
        1: alu_result = input1 | input2;
        2: alu_result = input1 + input2;
        3: alu_result = (input1 < input2)?1'b1:1'b0; //unsigned, no additional bits to worry about
        4: alu_result = input1 ^ input2;
        5: alu_result = ~(input1 | input2);
        6: alu_result = input1 - input2;
        7: alu_result = (~(input1 + 1) < input2)?1'b1:1'b0; //2's comp is ~ & +1
        default: alu_result = input1 & input2;
    endcase
    
    if(alu_result > 32'hFFFFFFFF)
    begin
        overflow <= alu_result;
    end
end
endmodule // alu
```

```
module datapath_tb();
parameter SIZE = 32;     
reg clk;
reg write;
reg [4:0] write_addr;
reg [31:0] write_data;
reg [4:0] read_addr1;
reg [4:0] read_addr2;
wire [31:0] read_data1;
wire [31:0] read_data2;
// Instantiate the register file
Register rf_1 (.clk(clk), .write_en(write), .write_addr(write_addr), .write_data(write_data), .read_addr1(read_addr1), .read_addr2(read_addr2), .read_data1(read_data1), .read_data2(read_data2));
// Instantiate the ALU
alu #(SIZE) alu_1 (.input1(read_data1), .input2(read_data2), .alu_result(write_data)); //Line in question
// Create a clocking signal
 always begin
   # 10;
   clk = 1; 
   # 10;
   clk = 0;
 end 

  initial begin
  // Write DIGIT0 into register 0
  
  // Write DIGIT1 into register 1

  end


endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your module ports as:

```
module alu #(parameter SIZE=32) (input wire [SIZE-1:0] input1, input2, 
                                       wire [2:0] control, 
                                 output reg [SIZE-1:0] alu_result,
                                        reg overflow );
```

Comment: That actually worked. Though I moved out ```control``` and ```overflow``` to declare locally. Now I'm just working on connecting it correctly on my datapath_tb module. "alu_result Must be connected to a structural or net expression" Thanks for your help.